# how to change label text when I hover mouse over a combobox item?

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I change the label text based on where I hover my mouse on combobox items?

for example [pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8Ra0.png)

when my mouse is over a item, but WITHOUT selecting it, I want the label to change to same text as the item where my mouse is over..
to change the text I do this

```
 flatLabel2.Text = flatComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString().ToUpper();
```

but cant find how to do it when mouse is hover a item, maybe I am googling in a wrong way.
anyone has any solution?

Comment: windows forms, fixed it easily with a timer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's WPF project, as I found before, you have to trigger MouseOver event on items by using **DependencyPropertyDescriptor** like this :

```
DependencyPropertyDescriptor dpd;
private void ComboBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBoxItem cmb = sender as ComboBoxItem;
    dpd = DependencyPropertyDescriptor
        .FromProperty(IsMouseOverProperty, typeof(ComboBoxItem));
    if (dpd != null)
        dpd.AddValueChanged(cmb, OnIsMouseOver);

}

private void ComboBox_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (dpd != null)
        dpd.RemoveValueChanged(cmb, OnIsMouseOver);

}

private void OnIsMouseOver(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBoxItem cmb = sender as ComboBoxItem;
    if (cmb.IsMouseOver)
    {
        //do something...
    }
}
```

and on view :

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmb">
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <EventSetter Event="Loaded" Handler="ComboBox_Loaded" />
            <EventSetter Event="Unloaded" Handler="ComboBox_Unloaded" />
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Yes, that's a good trick! and also if you want to reduce the count of threads you can do it without timer by using ***CompositionTarget.Rendering***

Comment: Wow! had no idea you could do that. Though it turns out it is WinForms