# Raise an event when I hover the mouse over a ComboBox item

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, combobox, custom-controls

I'm not able to find an event to fire when I hover my ComboBox Items.
I'm using windows form to build an application.
I found a something similar for WPF:
 [how to change label text when I hover mouse over a combobox item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51567198/how-to-change-label-text-when-i-hover-mouse-over-a-combobox-item).

How can I do it the similar way in Windows Forms, or is there an alternate way?

Class ComboBoxListEx:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

[DesignerCategory("Code")]
public class ComboBoxListEx : ComboBox
{
    private int listItem = -1;
    private const int CB_GETCURSEL = 0x0147;

    public event EventHandler<ListItemSelectionChangedEventArgs> ListItemSelectionChanged;

    protected virtual void OnListItemSelectionChanged(ListItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        => this.ListItemSelectionChanged?.Invoke(this, e);

    public ComboBoxListEx() { }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case CB_GETCURSEL:
                int selItem = m.Result.ToInt32();
                if (listItem != selItem)
                {
                    listItem = selItem;
                    OnListItemSelectionChanged(new ListItemSelectionChangedEventArgs(
                        listItem, listItem < 0 ? string.Empty : this.GetItemText(this.Items[listItem]))
                    );
                }
                break;
            default:
                // Add Case switches to handle other events
                break;
        }
    }

    public class ListItemSelectionChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public ListItemSelectionChangedEventArgs(int idx, string text)
        {
            this.ItemIndex = idx;
            this.ItemText = text;
        }
        public int ItemIndex { get; private set; }
        public string ItemText { get; private set; }
    }
}         


private void comboBoxListEx1_ListItemSelectionChanged(object sender, ComboBoxListEx.ListItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    label15.Text = e.ItemText;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a Custom Control, derived from ComboBox, override its [WndProc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.wndproc) method to intercept the [CB_GETCURSEL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cb-getcursel) message.

Call `base.WndProc(ref m)` first. When the message is processed, the [Message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.message) object's `m.Result` property is set to a value (as `IntPtr`) that represents the Item currently tracked in the ListBox (the Item highlighted when the Mouse Pointer hovers it).

► **Note:** prior to **.NET Framework 4.8**, the `CB_GETCURSEL` message result is not *bubbled up* automatically: we must send `LB_GETCURSEL` to the child ListBox to get the index of the Item currently *highlighted*.
The ListBox handle is retrieved using [GetComboBoxInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getcomboboxinfo): it could be also accessed using reflection (the private `ChildListAutomationObject` property returns the ListBox AutomationElement, which provides the handle), or sending a [`CB_GETCOMBOBOXINFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cb-getcomboboxinfo) message (but it's the same as calling `GetComboBoxInfo()`).

---

This custom ComboBox raises an Event, **`ListItemSelectionChanged`**, with a custom `EventArgs` object, **`ListItemSelectionChangedEventArgs`**, which exposes two public properties: **`ItemIndex`** and **`ItemText`**, set to the Index and Text of the hovered item.

---

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

[DesignerCategory("Code")]
public class ComboBoxListEx : ComboBox
{
    private const int CB_GETCURSEL = 0x0147;
    private int listItem = -1;
    IntPtr listBoxHandle = IntPtr.Zero;

    public event EventHandler<ListItemSelectionChangedEventArgs> ListItemSelectionChanged;

    protected virtual void OnListItemSelectionChanged(ListItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        => ListItemSelectionChanged?.Invoke(this, e);

    public ComboBoxListEx() { }

    // .NET Framework prior to 4.8 - get the handle of the ListBox
    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        listBoxHandle = GetComboBoxListInternal(this.Handle);
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        int selItem = -1;
        base.WndProc(ref m);

        switch (m.Msg) {
            case CB_GETCURSEL:
                selItem = m.Result.ToInt32();
                break;
            // .NET Framework prior to 4.8. Otherwise remove
            // case CB_GETCURSEL can be left there or removed: it's always -1
            case 0x0134: 
                selItem = SendMessage(listBoxHandle, LB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0);
                break;
            default:
                // Add Case switches to handle other events
                break;
        }
        if (listItem != selItem) {
            listItem = selItem;
            OnListItemSelectionChanged(new ListItemSelectionChangedEventArgs(
                listItem, listItem < 0 ? string.Empty : GetItemText(Items[listItem]))
            );
        }
    }

    public class ListItemSelectionChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public ListItemSelectionChangedEventArgs(int idx, string text) {
            ItemIndex = idx;
            ItemText = text;
        }
        public int ItemIndex { get; private set; }
        public string ItemText { get; private set; }
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------
    // .NET Framework prior to 4.8 only. Otherwise remove 
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    internal static extern bool GetComboBoxInfo(IntPtr hWnd, ref COMBOBOXINFO pcbi);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint uMsg, int wParam, int lParam);
    
    private const int LB_GETCURSEL = 0x0188;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct COMBOBOXINFO
    {
        public int cbSize;
        public Rectangle rcItem;
        public Rectangle rcButton;
        public int buttonState;
        public IntPtr hwndCombo;
        public IntPtr hwndEdit;
        public IntPtr hwndList;
        public void Init() => cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf<COMBOBOXINFO>();
    }

    internal static IntPtr GetComboBoxListInternal(IntPtr cboHandle)
    {
        var cbInfo = new COMBOBOXINFO();
        cbInfo.Init();
        GetComboBoxInfo(cboHandle, ref cbInfo);
        return cbInfo.hwndList;
    }
}
```

Works like this:

[image: ComboBox Custom List Hover Selection Events]

Comment: Perfect. Could you also tell me how to write this custom event in Designer.cs. Thanks a lot for explaining this in detail.

Comment: I wrote about it in the notes: in the Properties panel, click the Lightning icon ⚡: there you'll find the `ListItemSelectionChanged` event. Double click it, as usual, and a standard handler will be added to the Form's code.

Comment: This might be silly.. I was able to get everything working but I get the event fired only when clicked and not on MouseHover. The event code is 


private void comboBox31_ListItemSelectionChanged(object sender, ComboBoxListEx.ListItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
                   label15.Text = e.ItemText;            
        }
            and designer is 

            this.comboBox31.ListItemSelectionChanged += new System.EventHandler<ComboBoxListEx.ListItemSelectionChangedEventArgs>(this.comboBox31_ListItemSelectionChanged);

Comment: Thanks Jimi.. I have attached the class code in the body. I recreated the class again but still the event is firing only when I click on a listItem. Please forgive for bothering you again, I'm new to c#

Comment: I just copied what you pasted (but it's identical to what I posted here) and it works as expected. Try to: 1) build a new Project, with just one Form, 2) make a new class, named `ComboBoxListEx` and paste in this code, 3) Build the Solution, 4) Find the new Control in the ToolBox, 5) Drop it on the Form, 6) Add some items, 7) add a Label, next to the ComboBox (so, now you have `comboBoxListEx1` and `label1`), 8) Find the `ListItemSelectionChanged` Event in the Properties panel and double click it, to create the handler, 9) in the handler, add `label1.Text = e.ItemText`, 10) Run the Project.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 and .Net frameworks 4.7.2. I created a new form with just comboBoxListEx1 and added ListItemSelectionChanged, but it triggers only when I click on the listItem. Now I'm really curious to know the issue :)

Comment: Argh! Framework 4.7.2. Well, that's my fault, I should have mentioned it: you need at least FW 4.8 to receive a `CB_GETCURSEL` message from the child ListBox. If you can update your FW, better, but I'll see to make it compatible with older Frameworks.

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks Jimi. Yes if I can get this compatible with older frameworks that would really help as I'm planning to deploy this application on PC's with windows 10 and as windows 10 has 4.6 installed by default, they wont have to update frameworks just for this application. Please let me know if its possible with older frameworks, else I will have to include the 4.8 installer along with application so everyone can update and then use the application.

Comment: All right, I've added a patch that should make it work anywhere. You can substitute the previous class with this one. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Perfect.. Thanks a lot Jimi. It worked like charm and thanks for spoon feeding me the complete data. Thank you so much.