# C# remove combobox items by right clicking on them

Tags: c#, winforms, events, combobox

I am trying to make items in a combobox disappear when I right click on them.  I have messed around with the mouse down and mouse click events but they only seem to fire when clicking on the control itself and not individual items in the drop down list.

```
private void CmbChildValues_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Right Click Mouse Down");
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Probably should specify which kind of ComboBox you're talking about. WinForms, WPF, WebForms, etc.???

Comment: Sorry winform combobox!

Comment: Without having tested it, you'll probably have to sub-class the ComboBox class and override the `WndProc` method and intercept a `WM_NOTIFY` or `WM_REFLECT_NOTIFY` for MouseButtonDown.

Comment: You can use [GetComboBoxInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getcomboboxinfo) to get the handle of the ListControl of your ComboBox (the Control that shows the list of the ComboBox Items), then handle its events, as MouseClick etc. An example here: [Raise an event when I hover the mouse over a ComboBox item](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61154093/7444103): that code handles the ListControl and generates an event when the Mouse hovers over its items. You can do the same thing with a MouseClick and remove the Item where the Click event is generated.