# how to select index in a combobox using DOWN ARROW key?

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, combobox, ado.net

[I want this functionality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjG52.gif)my combobox has multiple values. for example: RJ11, RJ12, RJ13 and so on.
AutoCompleteMode set to append and AutoCompleteSource set to listItems. all i want is when i type rj in combobox it will suggest me rj11 in combobox's text field and when i press DOWN ARROW key it should select rj11 but what it is doing is it keep searching for next possible match.

i tried :

```
private void comboBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
        {
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = comboBox1.FindStringExact(comboBox1.Text);
        }
    }
```

but it is not working.
i am very new to winform and programing.
please help.
and yeah sorry for my bad english.

Comment: A selection is finalized when you press the Enter key. No need set anything in the KeyDown handler.

Comment: @Jimi how can i set it to Arrow Down key or any other Key i want instead of Enter ?

Comment: Not sure why you'd want to override the default behavior people are used to, in this context. Anyway, if you want to perform any action when the selection on the ListControl is moved, you can use this Custom Control: [Raise an event when I hover the mouse over a ComboBox item](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61154093/7444103). It was designed for .Net FW 4.8 (using the new features of this version), but then modified to be compatible with previous versions of the Framework. It should also work in .Net 5, but not tested.

Comment: You need to subscribe to the public `ListItemSelectionChanged` event to receive a notification when an element of the ListControl is selected / highlighted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to refer to the following code to select the index in a combobox by using down key.

We can override the ProcessCmdkey method in your form.

Code:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
        {
            if ((this.ActiveControl == comboBox1) && (keyData == Keys.Down))
            {
                comboBox1.SelectedIndex = comboBox1.FindStringExact(comboBox1.Text);
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
            }
        }
```

Comment: thank you so much sir for your time and  this is what i wanted but there is a problem. now i am not able to move to the next index when i press Down Arrow Key. i updated my question with GIF demo.

Comment: @prashant, I make a new answer in the new question. You can take a look at it.