# The mouse scroll event in the combobox

Tags: vb.net

How do I know the mouse scrolling action in the combobox? At the same time I can get the current position of the scroll bar in the combobox

Comment: https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?758781-How-can-I-catch-scroll-event-in-combobox-(like-Scroll-event-in-VB6)-in-vb-net

Comment: What do you need the scroll position for? If you want to know which item is currently *highlighted* in the DropDown list of a ComboBox, see here: [Raise an event when I hover the mouse over a ComboBox item](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61154093/7444103). Otherwise, try to explain what you actually want.