# detect which item cursor is over in winform datagridviewcombobox

Tags: c#, winforms, mousehover, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I have a datagridview that contains a column of datagridviewcomboboxs. An adjacent column needs to be updated based on the item the mouse is currently over (prior to selecting it. User selections are already handled). Ultimately, I am just trying to show the user what units are associated with the item the mouse is over to help with their selection.

For example, in the attached image when the user moves the mouse from the second item in the datagridviewcombobox to the third, the adjacent column should reflect an associated string that is dependant on the combobox item. So in this case "g" may become "m/s".

[image: datagridview image]

I have been trying to find a solution for a while now. It is probably something simple but I have not been able to make progress.

Comment: That screenshot looks horrible and explains nothing.

Comment: Looks like a custom paint job. It would be simpler to put the units into the combo text, no?

Comment: Have you had a look at [EditingControlShowing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.editingcontrolshowing?view=net-5.0)?

Comment: [Raise an event when I hover the mouse over a ComboBox item](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61154093/7444103) -- You need to replace the default ComboBox control of a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn with this Custom Control (hence, better use a Custom Column).

Comment: @CaiusJard I was hoping to keep them separate but I suppose it does not need to be.

Comment: Just seems like one of those headaches that should be put on the back burner until you have time for that degree of UI fluffing..

Comment: @ThomasWeller I think the image comment is a matter of forest and trees. The information item string should not be needed and was intentionally obscured. Maybe it was not necessary to include the image altogether but that was a worth while comment. I am glad you are here to help...

Comment: @ThomasWeller I have tried some things with EditControlShowing prior to posting the question. I think I will run with Caius Jard's suggestion for now.

Comment: @CaiusJard I agree but rabbit holes are fun and easy to go down...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Raise an event when I hover the mouse over a ComboBox item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61152847/raise-an-event-when-i-hover-the-mouse-over-a-combobox-item)