# How to get the index of a ComboBox dropdown list item at the mouse position?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, mouseover

Is it possible in to get the index of a ComboBox item when the mouse is over an item of the dropdown list?
Thanks for help.

Comment: look at https://github.com/MaxBGitHub/MouseOverItemComboBox

Comment: thanks for the hint and your quick response. I will try this out. So there is no easier way?

Comment: [Raise an event when I hover the mouse over a ComboBox item](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61154093/7444103) -- Read the note and the comments. It's quite simplified if you target .NET Framework 4.8+ or .NET 5+; latest updates to the framework *bubble up* the `CB_GETCURSEL` message, so you're notified when the mouse hovers over an item in the list