# Raise an event when hovering over items in a DataGridViewComboBoxCell

Tags: datagridview, combobox

Using Visual Studio 2022, Framework 4.8, Windows Form Application, VB.NET Project.

On the Form I have a Datagridview with 3 columns
Within col2 Row(0) - I've set it to DataGridViewComboBoxCell with set items, when the user selects an item it pre-populates the second row with another DataGridViewComboBoxCell.

I have managed to do this thru DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl events.

While breaking into DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl (which it inherits Combobox control)
I feel this is in the right area (I think) but I dont know how to incorporate the Hover function from link ([Raise an event when I hover the mouse over a ComboBox item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61152847/raise-an-event-when-i-hover-the-mouse-over-a-combobox-item)
Appreciate it is in C# managed to convert to vb.net and got error and thats far as I got)??

Trying to tap into the combobox control to get back the index of the item the user is hovering over so I can add a list box to visually show further details of the option before deciding on their selection.

```
 Private Sub DataGridView2_EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView2.EditingControlShowing

     If sender.selectedcells.count = 1 Then
         If sender.selectedcells(0).rowindex < 4 Then
             cbEdit = TryCast(e.Control, DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl)
             If cbEdit IsNot Nothing Then
                 AddHandler cbEdit.SelectionChangeCommitted, cbEdit_SelectionChangeComittedHandler
             End If
         Else
             cbEdit = TryCast(e.Control, DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl)
             If cbEdit IsNot Nothing Then
                 AddHandler cbEdit.SelectionChangeCommitted, cbEdit_SelectionHoverComittedHandler
             End If

         End If
     End If

 End Sub
```

When ever a combobox is triggered within the datagridview it goes thru here, the point in question is in the Else part of the statement. This is where I tried to get the hover to work but to no avail.
Its like I need to link the Combobox to the editing control to the hover or vice versa the hover within the Combobox thru the editing control??

I've copied the working part to emulate the hover in the main class variables

```
Public Class Form1

    Private cbEdit As DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl
    Private cbEdit_SelectionChangeComittedHandler As New EventHandler(AddressOf cbEdit_SelectionChangeCommitted)

 ** *  Private cbEdit_SelectionHoverComittedHandler As New EventHandler(AddressOf comboBoxListEx1_ListItemSelectionChanged)***


When scrolling thru the specific Combobox items (thru the Else Part of the code above) it should (would like it to) trigger this, but no!!!

    Private Sub comboBoxListEx1_ListItemSelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As ListItemSelectionChangedEventArgs)

        Label12.Text = e.ItemText       'Test to see if it worked

    End Sub
```

.. to the Else part of the statement and now I feel I'm way over my head and need some help.

Can provide more code if need, and hope this makes sense!!
Thanks in advance..